# Динамически включать/выключать условие в SELECT..WHERE в зависимости от параметра

Tags: sql-server, запрос

Использую SQL Server 2012 и оператор SELECT внутри хранимой процедуры. Процедура принимает несколько параметров, один из которых является ключевым в настоящем вопросе. Вот псевдокод процедуры:

```
create proc MyProc
    @mid tinyint,
    @param1 bit = 0
as

    set nocount on

    select
    p.RowId,
    i.Sku,
    i.Condition,
    p.OldPrice,
    p.Delta

    from Prices p 
    join Items i on (p.Sku = i.Sku)

    where
    (p.Mid = @mid)
    and (i.Quantity > 0)
    and (i.IsNew = 0)

    --Нужно чтобы условие ниже выполнялось в зависимости от param1
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    and not (p.Delta = 0 and p.CurrentPrice = p.pMin)
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------

    and p.ThreadId = @thread_id
    order by p.Delta desc
```

То есть по умолчанию (при `param1 = 0`) это условие должно выполняться, а если `param1 = 1` то оно не должно выполняться, как будто его там и нет.

Я попытался поиграться с булевыми операторами, но у меня, увы, ничего не получается. Есть ли у вас какие-то идеи?

Да, вот еще что: я принципиально не хочу связываться с динамическим SQL со всякими конкатенцаиями строк и так далее. Я люблю мои прекомпилируемые хранимые процедуры и хочу использовать именно динамические возможности включения/выключения WHERE-условий.

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**

Задавая вопрос, я рассчитывал получить конкретное условие (набор boolean expressions), которое будет работать. Вместо этого, уважаемые коллеги оценили в комментариях "мой подход к решению" задачи. Как известно, ни один разработчик не задаст вопроса, содержащего реальных данных, параметров, условий, названий полей, и пр. Вопросы тут прототипируются для того, чтобы получить советы по реализации и затем перенести все в реальную разработку. Мой вопрос - не исключение.

> В реальной задаче, **процедура принимает 12-ть (!) параметров** типа
>   `bit` и строит запрос исходя из состояния битов.

Уважаемые коллеги в комментариях раскритиковали мой подход и предложили написать два `SELECT`-запроса, разделённых оператором `if`. Теперь мой встречный вопрос: сколько разветвлений `if` вы мне порекомендуете для того, чтобы реализовать разные состояния 12-ти битов? По-прежнему ли вы считаете мой подход неправильным *в рамках решения моей конкретной задачи*?

Comment: Ну да... типичное поведение на русском SO - минуснуть вопрос и ничем это не пояснить. Не пойму: у меня что-то с вопросом не так?

Comment: Не с вопросом, а с подходом к решению задачи. Надо было написАть два запроса - с условием и без,- и внешней для этого запроса проверкой в зависимости от значения параметра выполнять нужный из них. Универсальность зачастую противоречит эффективности - и здесь тот самый случай.

Comment: @Akina, я совершенно с этим несогласен. Писать два запроса - то же самое, что и хранить дубликаты в базе. Это дурной тон, об этом рассказывают в первом классе.

Comment: Да пжалста, пишите один. Только потом не спрашивайте, почему это он такой тормознутый... Насчёт дурного тона - это Вас кто-то обманул. Ещё в первом классе. То, что эффективно - не может быть дурным тоном.

Comment: @InterfaceUnknown одинаковый текст запроса подразумевает один и тот же план выполнения (вы же любите прекомпилируемые процедуры). А значит даже если вы как-то  спустите `param1 = 1` - SQL Server все равно выберет данные под условие и все равно его проверит. Выбирать данные, заведомо зная что они не понадобяться - дурной тон :)

Comment: `ни один разработчик не задаст вопроса, содержащего реальных данных, параметров, условий, названий полей, и пр. Вопросы тут прототипируются для того, чтобы` - далеко не всегда это прототипирование выполняется полностью адекватно.

Comment: `встречный вопрос: сколько разветвлений if вы мне порекомендуете для того, чтобы реализовать разные состояния 12-ти битов?` Укажи Вы это сразу - и Вам было бы предложено сразу же посмотреть в сторону динамического построения запроса.

Comment: @InterfaceUnknown если вы так уверены, что все остальные разбираются в вашем подходе хуже вас - зачем вы вообще задаете вопрос? Подалуйста, воздержитесь от беспочвенных выпадов в сторону других участников. Если хотите пообсуждать как опыт, репутация и знание sql портит людей - обсуждайте это на мете или в чате.

Comment: @InterfaceUnknown раз вы так хотите ответ без указаний и без советов - я его с удовольствием дам. Надеюсь, он окажется вам дико полезным :)

Answer (score 2):

> по умолчанию (при param1 = 0) это условие должно выполняться, а если param1 = 1 то оно не должно выполняться, как будто его там и нет.

```
WHERE ... AND ((условие) OR (param1 = 1)) AND ...
```

Конкретно для Вашего условия можно создать более эффективную конструкцию:

```
and not (p.Delta = 0 and p.CurrentPrice = p.pMin and param1 = 0)
```

Comment: Стоит отметить, что даже в случае `param1 = 1` SQL Server все равно выберет данные под `условие` и все равно его проверит, т.к. план он строит общий для всех значений параметров, и просто так выбросить кусок плана не может. Т.е. будет работать медленнее, чем при использовании двух разных запросов и `if`

Comment: Несомненно. Почему я и говорю выше, что два отдельных запроса эффективнее.

Answer (score 0):

У SQL Server нет способа динаически выключить WHERE со строгим соблюдением ваших условий:

```
если param1 = 1 то оно не должно выполняться, как будто его там и нет
```

Это вызвано тем, что SQL всегда строит план выполнения запроса, который будет применим для любых значений параметров. И кеширует его на будущее.

Соответственно, выполние условия (выборка данных под него, фильтрация и прочее) всегда будет частью плана и частью выполнения, вне зависимости от значений параметров.

Для получения плана выполнения без фильтрации вам придется поменять текст запроса, а динамический SQL (который тоже отлично компилируется) вы строго запретили вам советовать.

---

Ваш подход (через OR) может оказаться правильным, а может оказаться и неправильным в рамках решения вашей конкретной задачи.

Во первых, он, строго говоря, не соответствует вашему же требованию "как будто его там и нет".

Во вторых, он потенциально вызывает проблемы с производительностью на реальных объемах данных. Является ли большой объем данных частью вашей задачи - никто, кроме вас, не знает.